# Div inside Div stripe not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create striped divs that are similar to a stripe spreadsheet. I am working on creating a format that relies on a table created by divs.

When I am trying to implement either `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`, I keep getting a broken output. Can somebody help me? I have been trying to find a solution but no avail.

This is my code.

HTML

```
<div>
  <div class="tab1">
    1
    <div class="tab2">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="tab1">
    3
    <div class="tab2">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

on repeat...

CSS

```
.tab1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.tab2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
div:nth-of-type(odd) .tab1 {
  background-color: green;
}
.tab1:nth-child(odd) .tab2{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abnqo501/

edit:
It should be returning green, yellow, red then orange for the color stripes in that order.

If someone can help me scale this as well, that would be nice.

If I wanted to expand and add another div, such as

```
<div>
  <div class="tab1">
     1
     <div>
       2
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

how would I change the syntax? from `div:nth-child(odd) > .tab1 tab2`

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't add `.tab3` and `.tab4` and add the other 2 colors? Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kyegs9o3/1/)

Comment: because it's easier to read to see 1234, 1234, 1234, etc... to help people understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: also, the website will be dynamic instead of static. its coming out of a php script

Comment: `.tab1:nth-child(odd)` this will be always odd-numbered, because `.tab1` is the only element in that level.

Comment: Does the html structure have to be like that? or can you change it if needed?

Comment: must be like that or something similar. Cannot use tables. If the website would be static, then there is no need for this at all.

Comment: @Huelfe, even if I change it to `.tab2:nth-child(odd)`, it still doesnt work :3

Comment: @user3435505 have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment `.tab1:nth-child(odd)` will be always odd-numbered, because .tab1 is the only element in that level.

So you have to use this css:

```
div:nth-child(odd) > .tab1 .tab2{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Have a look:

```css
.tab1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.tab2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
div:nth-of-type(odd) .tab1 {
  background-color: green;
}
div:nth-child(odd) > .tab1 .tab2{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="tab1">
    1
    <div class="tab2">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="tab1">
    3
    <div class="tab2">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div>
  <div class="tab1">
    1
    <div class="tab2">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="tab1">
    3
    <div class="tab2">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div>
  <div class="tab1">
    1
    <div class="tab2">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="tab1">
    3
    <div class="tab2">
      4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

---

After you edited your question, the code will be the following:

```css
.tab1 {
  background-color: red;
}

div:nth-child(even) > .tab1 > div {
  background-color: orange;
}

div:nth-of-type(odd) .tab1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.tab1:nth-child(odd) > div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <div class="tab1"> 1 
    <div> 2 </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
<div> 
  <div class="tab1"> 3 
    <div> 4 </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: quick question, 
if I wanted to expand to 

    `<div>
      <div class="tab1">
         1
         <div>
           2
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>`

how would I change the syntax?